# Protractor - get child element of an element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, typescript, protractor

I am trying to access child element of an ng-repeat element but I am having troubles doing that.

I have searched around about the problem and the solutions that I have found did not work for me. One of those solutions was to do something like this:

```
var parent = element(by.repeater(''));
var child = parent.element(by.....);
```

When I try the `child` line I cant see the element function on the parent element..

http://prikachi.com/images/11/8338011u.png

If you see the screenshot above you will see the structure of the code of the page that I am trying to test.

I need to access the alt attribute of the image of the avatar and get its value (thats the Username of the User).

One thing that came to my mind is to use `.getInnerHTML()` on the ng-repeat row which will return a string with all that code. From there I can find the `alt` attribute and its value with string manipulation but this seems too brute and I am sure that there has to be a better way.

Simply I want to be able to get row 4 from the repeater and get the Username of the user at row 4, that's all I wanna do actually.

Answer (score 6):

Try this,

```
var parent = element(by.repeater('f in feed'));
var child = parent.all(by.xpath('//img[@alt="Pundeep"]')).first()
```

(or)

```
var parent = element(by.repeater('f in feed'));
var child = parent.all(by.xpath('//img[@alt="Pundeep"]')).get(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I am trying to do something different I want to get the 4th element for example (or the first in my example above) in the repeater and then get the value of the alt attribute and see if its the correct username. 1. Get 4th row in the repeater, 2. Get the value of the alt tag of the image of the username, 3. Save that value in a variable for later use.

Answer (score 3):

You can get it directly using `element.all()` and `get()` locator in protractor. Here's how -

```
var child = element.all(by.repeater('parent_locator')).get(3); //gets 4th element in repeater. Its a 0 based index.
child.getAttribute('alt').then(function(user){
    var username = user; //username contains the alt text
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: While this works, it becomes complicated with complex documents.

Answer (score 2):

In Protractor element documentation it gives an example like this to find child elements, which is same as chaining element find:

```
// Chain 2 element calls.
let child = element(by.css('.parent')).
    $('.child');
expect(child.getText()).toBe('Child text\n555-123-4567');

// Chain 3 element calls.
let triple = element(by.css('.parent')).
    $('.child').
    element(by.binding('person.phone'));
expect(triple.getText()).toBe('555-123-4567');

// Or using the shortcut $() notation instead of element(by.css()):

// Chain 2 element calls.
let child = $('.parent').$('.child');
expect(child.getText()).toBe('Child text\n555-123-4567');

// Chain 3 element calls.
let triple = $('.parent').$('.child').
    element(by.binding('person.phone'));
expect(triple.getText()).toBe('555-123-4567');
```

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$

Comment: This requires classes to be defined.  Also, it looks for descendants not the direct child from the previous element.

Answer (score 1):

this example could help :

```
return element(by.css('select.custom-select:nth-child(1) option[value="12"]'));
```

you can use nth-child() selector to access to a child element.
In my example i used a plugin with 2 select with same classes and i wanted to click on a defined option in the select 1, and a second in the select 2.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This searches for descendants not the direct child.